# C++: making a single file without includes

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor, single-file

This might sound like a very weird question, but I do need this: I have a bunch of c++ header files (from some header-only libraries) and a single cpp file. What I'd like to do is generate a single cpp file that has no includes whatsoever.

Why? For a contest, in which the compiler doesn't have some libraries I'm using, and one in which you can only submit one single cpp file.

Ideally, this "script" would create a file that uses only what is actually needed, not just copy and paste recursively all "#includes".

I'm sure that the preprocessor generates some files when you add an "#include" in the code. So, how can I see these intermediate and (probably very long) files?

Comment: Consult your compiler's reference manual. Most compilers allow you to write preprocessed output to disk.

Answer (score 8):

- **GCC** provides the `-E` option, so it stops after preprocessing the files. The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.5/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) has more options that can be applied to the preprocessor.
- **clang** also accepts `-E`, as stated [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#cmdoption-E).
- **Visual Studio** provides the [/P (Preprocess to a File)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx) compiler switch. It instructs the compiler to:

  > Preprocess[es] C and C++ source files and write[s] the preprocessed output to a file.

  The output is written to a file with a file name based on the source file with an .i extension. To specify a different file name, use the [/Fi (Preprocess Output File Name)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207218.aspx) compiler switch.
- **Intel C++ Compiler** will stop after preprocessing if you pass either the `-E` option (outputs to `stdout`) or `-P` (outputs to a file). On Windows these will be the `/E` and `/P` switches respectively. The [manual](https://www.cms.hu-berlin.de/de/dl/systemservice/computeservice/docs/intel_c_ug.pdf) has more information on this.